# entity framwork - saving ref property to same table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have this class (simplified):

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("Customers")]
        public virtual Customer ParentCustomer { get; set; }

        [InverseProperty("ParentCustomer")]
        public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I try to update the "ParentCustomer" it is not working, I try to update it like this:

```
var currCostumer = context.Customers.First(a => a.ID == key);
currCostumer.ParentCustomer = context.Customers.First(a => a.ID == 12);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I have tried both in a transaction and without. I can see in the sql generated that it does update all fields except this ParentCustomer (ParentCustomerID) field. If I try to retrieve my "currCustomer" like the following, I can still see it is referencing the correct customer. But not if I try it in a new webapi request.

```
var currCostumer = context.Customers.First(a => a.ID == key);
// currCostumer.ParentCustomer is correct here (if same request)
```

This is the model builder:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Customer>("Customer");
```

Comment: where is PreferredReseller? please describe models correct

Comment: Were those classes generated by Entity Framework or manually by you? Do the entities have a properly configured relationship?

Comment: Sorry, "PreferredReseller" should have been ParentCustomer.

Comment: Have you skipped some relevant information (like explicit FK property or fluent configuration), because the way you posted it, it works for me (EF6.1.3)?

Comment: My entity framework version is 6.0.0

Comment: I have added the model builder as well

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, your code sample works for me (the parent gets updated). What you can try is to not rely on the lazy loading and eager load the `ParentCustomer` property before modifying it, e.g. something like `var currCostumer = context.Customers.Include(e => e.ParentCustomer).First(a => a.ID == key);` and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. When I knew this code was correct I tested the same code in a different webapi method and then it worked. I originally had it in the "PUT" method of odata3 api. But when I manually created a post method and tested the same code in it it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ModelBuilder configuration that should work for such self-referencing parent - child relationships. I also like to expose the foreign key in the model.

```
public class Customer {
    public virtual Customer ParentCustomer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Exposed foreign key of the <see cref="ParentCustomer "/>.
    /// This is optional (might be null), because not every Customer is grouped into another Customer .
    /// </summary>
    public long? ParentCustomerId { get; set; }
}

ModelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
   .HasMany(x => x.Customers)
   .WithOptional(x => x.ParentCustomer)    // Not all Customers are contained in a parent Customer, therefore this relationship is optional
   .HasForeignKey(x => x.ParentCustomerId)
   .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);            // ON DELETE NO ACTION constraint is necessary or we would introduce multiple cascade paths
```

Note that you have to manually implement the correct deletion behavior, because we can not use cascade delete in this case.

Comment: But that's the default relationship mapping by convention with the OP provided model - navigation properties only, no fluent configuration, just the shadow FK name is `ParentCustomer_Id`.

Comment: I don't know the exact behavior of `[InverseProperty]` because we configure all our relationships using the fluent API. The config given above works for us in production.

Comment: I currently do not map any relationships in the modelbuilder, is it a requirement for this setup?

Comment: As I said, I do not know how to configure this setup using DataAnnotations attributes because I never done it this way. Might be possible to do it with attributes only.